# Linq to strikeout Telerik datagrid row

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, telerik, telerik-grid

I am using `asp.net 3.5` with `c#`. I am getting records in `dataset` that contains a field with name `IsDeleted`. Now for this field, if it is set to `true` then I want to strikeout the entire row's text.

For example : I am making `Capital Case` the text of field `Alert` using `linq` code below :

```
ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().ToList().ForEach(i => i["Alert"] = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(i["Alert"].ToString()));
```

Something like this is possible `to strikeout the entire row's text?`

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to get rid of it or to apply a style that is like `<strike>`?

Comment: Actually I want to apply strickout style if the field IsDeleted = true

Comment: Which Telerik product are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously `TextInfo` doesn't have any method to do such modification, since it's applied in HTML only.

You can however add the HTML `text-decoration` to every cell.
Try this:

```
ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().ToList()
          .Where(i=>i["IsDeleted"].ToString().Equals("True"))
          .ForEach(i => 
          {
              i["Alert"] = "<span style='text-decoration:line-through;'>" + 
                           i["Alert"].ToString() +
                           "</span>";
              i["Name"] = "<span style='text-decoration:line-through;'>" + 
                           i["Name"].ToString() +
                           "</span>";
              i["Date"] = "<span style='text-decoration:line-through;'>" + 
                           i["Date"].ToString() +
                           "</span>";
          });
```

Comment: One more question, what if I want to strikeout more columns in same statement?? For example, here we have strikeout only "Alert" column, but same way also want to strikeout two other columns "Name" and "Date". Is it possible in same statement??

Comment: Yes you can using the same logic but adding brackets to include more than one modification. See edited answer